# Derivative of riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I dont understand the following detail

$$ \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b \frac{d}{dt}(g(X,X)ds = \int_a^bg(\nabla_YX, X)$$

Here $X = d\phi (\partial/\partial s)$ and $Y =d\phi (\partial/\partial t)$.
Where $\phi:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\times I \rightarrow M : \phi: (t,s) \rightarrow \phi(t,s)$.

In our course we define $\textbf{metric}$ as a connection $\nabla$ such that 
$$X(g(Y,Z) = g(\nabla_XY,Z) + g(\nabla_XZ,Y),$$ where $X,Y,Z$ is vector fields.

I fail to see why this is true.
Can someone please explain.

Comment: I always thought $g$ was the metric...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course, metric *is not* a connection. However, for a Riemannian metric $g$ one defines (and uses!) $g$-compatible connections $\nabla$ such that the parallel transport via $\nabla$ preserves the metric $g$. Equivalently, for all smooth vector fields $X, Y, Z$:
$$
X(g(Y,Z))= g(\nabla_X Y, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z). 
$$
This will be explained in pretty much any Riemannian Geometry textbook (my personal favorite is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry"). You can think of this formula as the "product rule" for the differentiation via the vector field $X$.

Edit. Here are some details ("low brow", avoiding discussion of pull-back of bundles and connections), mostly following do Carmo's book "Riemannian Geometry":

Definition. An affine connection $\nabla$ on a manifold $M$ is said to be compatible with a Riemannian metric $g$ if parallel transport along curves defined by $\nabla$ preserves the metric $g$.

Step 1. (Proposition 3.2 in do Carmo's book) A connection $\nabla$ is compatible with $g$ if and only if for every curve $c: I\to M$ and a pair of vector field $V, W$ along $c$, we have the "Riemannian Product Rule"
$$
(1)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ \frac{d}{dt} g(V,W)= g(\frac{DV}{dt}, W) +  g(V, \frac{DW}{dt}). 
$$
The proof (in do Carmo) of the non-obvious implication (from compatibility to the product rule) is rather straightforward, by writing $V, W$ in terms of orthonormal parallel bases of vector fields along $c$ and then applying the Product Rule from Calculus.

Step 2. (Corollary 3.3  in do Carmo's book):  A connection $\nabla$ is compatible with $g$ if and only if
$$
(2)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ X(g(Y,Z))= g(\nabla_X Y, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z) 
$$
for all vector fields $X, Y, Z$ on $M$.

Proof. Suppose that  $\nabla$ is compatible with $g$. Take $p\in M$ and let $c: I\to M$ be a curve with $c(t_0)=p, c'(t_0)=X(p)$. Then (by Step 1)
$$
X(p) g(Y,Z)= \frac{d}{dt} g(Y,Z)|_{t_0}= g_p(\nabla_{X(p)} Y, Z) + g_p(Y, \nabla_{X(p)} Z),
$$
hence, implying the equation (2). For the opposite implication do Carmo goofed (one of the few places in the book where he did) and said that it is obvious (it is not). Here is the proof.

Define the closed subset $J\subset I$ to be the critical set of $c$, i.e. $J$ consists of points $t$ such that $c'(t)=0$.

Case a. Suppose that $t_0\notin J$. Then there is an open interval $I_0\subset I$ containing $t_0$ such that $c|_{I_0}$
is an embedding. Hence, the vector fields $V, W$ along $c$, restricted to $I_0$ extend to smooth vector fields $Y, Z$ on $M$, while the tangent field $c'|_{I_0}$ extends to a vector field $X$ on $M$. Now, the equation (1) at $t_0$ indeed immediately follows from the equation (2).

Case b. Suppose that $t_0$ belongs to the interior of $J$. Then there is an open interval $I_0\subset I$ containing $t_0$ such that $c$ is constant on $I_0$, $c(t)=p, t\in I_0$. Then we do not even need the metric compatibility condition and the proof is a Calculus argument. The vector fields $V, W$ along $c$, restricted to $I_0$ become smooth maps $I_0\to T_pM$. Then, writing   $\frac{D}{dt}$ in local coordinates at $p$ (where $g_p=\delta_{ij}$) we obtain:
$$
\frac{DV}{dt}= \frac{dV}{dt}, \frac{DW}{dt}= \frac{dW}{dt}
$$
(the "calculus derivative" for maps $V, W: I_0\to T_pM$). Indeed, writing $V=\sum_i v^i e_i$, where $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis in $T_pM$, we have
$$
\frac{DV}{dt}= \sum_k \left( \frac{dv^k}{dt} + \sum_{i,j} v^j c'_i(t_0)  \Gamma^k_{ij}\right)e_k=  \sum_k \frac{dv^k}{dt}e_k =\frac{dV}{dt},
$$
since $c'(t_0)=0$.

Thus, on the interval $I_0$, we have
$$
g_p(V,W)= V\cdot W
$$
and the equation
$$
\frac{d}{dt} V\cdot W= \frac{dV}{dt} \cdot W +  V\cdot \frac{dW}{dt} 
$$
is just the Product Rule from Calculus.

Case c. Suppose that $t_0\in I$ lies on the boundary of $J$. Then the equality (1) follows from Case (a) by continuity.

When I teach RG (I use do Carmo's book), I usually give this proof and later on discuss connections on general vector bundles and explain that vector fields along curves/surfaces are sections of pull-back bundles and that  $\frac{D}{dt}$ is the pull-back connection and then give a "high-brow" proof of the fact that pull-back of a parallel covariant tensor is again parallel.

Comment: I have the same question and do not think the accepted answer is convincing since $\partial /\partial t$ is not a vector field on $M$, the underlying manifold

Comment: @Chee: It *is* a vector field on a neighborhood of the curve in question. Use a partition of unity to extend to a global vector field.

Comment: @Ted: thank you for your reply. But $\partial / \partial t$ is a vector field on the open interval of the real line.

Comment: @Chee No, if you read carefully, you'll see it's pushed forward to $M$ by $\phi$. You may want to assume $\phi$ is injective, I guess. You can also approach this by pulling back by $\phi$ and applying this to $\phi^*g$.

Comment: @Ted: thank you. did you mean that $\partial /\partial t$ acting on $g(X,X)$ requires varying curves in the family of curves generated by $\phi$, thus triggering the tangent map of $\phi$ and activating covariant derivative?

Comment: @Chee I do not know what your question is: I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: @TedShifrin, you in fact don’t want to assume $\phi$ is injective, because it’s not always so when working with Jacobi fields. So pushing forward is not a satisfactory answer. Every differential geometry text I’ve ever seen dodges this issue. You in fact have to pull back the tangent bundle and connection to the 2-manifold. And doing that isn’t totally straightforward. There’s a discussion of this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49272/pull-back-connection

Comment: @Chee: I think, what you are really asking is: "How does one define covariant derivative of a vector-field (or a tensor-field) along a curve/surface?" This is a good question which is usually explained in Differential Geometry textbooks, but it is not what the original question was (and the original question was quite muddled and based on a misconception). And the right answer, as Deane says, is through the notion of a *pull-back* (of bundles and of connections).

Comment: There seems to be two separate questions here: How to prove the first equation, and how to prove the second. If you don't assume that $\phi$ is an embedding, then the first does not follow directly from the second equation. You can prove each one separately by writing them in local coordinates and carrying out the differentiation. The proofs will look nearly identical. But this way of proving the first equation works for any smooth map $\phi$ without any further assumptions.

Comment: @Deane: Right. When I was answering the question, I was assuming that OP is asking about the second equation. Given the 2nd equation, the first one becomes a special case of the statement: Suppose that $E\to M$ is a vector bundle with a connection $\nabla$ and $\phi: M'\to M$ is a smooth map, $E'\to M'$ is the pull-back bundle (via $\phi$) with the pull-back connection $\nabla'=\phi^*\nabla$. Then: If a (covariant) tensor $\tau$ on $E$ is parallel under $\nabla$, then the pull-back $\phi^*(\tau)$ is also $\nabla'$-parallel.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, agreed but that assumes that one knows what the definitions of a pullback bundle and connection are under a smooth map that's not an immersion. It's not obvious, and I've never seen this discussed in a differential geometry textbook. Do you know a reference? I even wrote up the definitions carefully here: https://www.math.nyu.edu/~yangd/papers/pullback.pdf. But when I teach this, I just demonstrate it using local coordinates and avoid this discussion.

Comment: @Deane: Sadly, I do not have a good reference. When I teach a RG class, I spend quite a bit of time discussing general vector bundles, connections, pull-back and then give the pull-back of a Riemannian connection via a general smooth map as an example of why one should care about connections on vector bundles even in the RG context. I define pull-back of a connection via a local computation and then leave it as an exercise to prove that the construction is independent of the local trivialization.

Comment: @Ted, Deane, Moishe: thank you a lot for all your help. I looked into the proof Proposition 5.5 of Lee's book "Introduction to Riemannian manifolds", which talks about $\frac{d}{dt} \langle V,W \rangle= \langle D_t V, W \rangle + \langle V, D_t W \rangle$. The proof is in local coordinates. Still I am stuck at why $\frac{d}{dt} \langle \partial_i, \partial_j \rangle = \langle \nabla_{\gamma^{\prime}(t)} \partial_i, \partial_j \rangle + \langle  \partial_i, \nabla_{\gamma^{\prime}(t)} \partial_j \rangle$. Where does pull-back play a role?

Comment: @Chee: I don't consider this a pullback situation at all. It's using the fact that $\nabla$ is a derivation that commutes with contractions. After all, the LHS is $\nabla_{\gamma'(t)}$ as well. ... One last comment on the previous discussion. My way around these issues (much as I love pullback bundles, they aren't really needed here) is to work with moving frames and the Cartan structure equations, and it's easy enough to define a frame field on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times I$. We can be fancy and talk about pulling back the frame bundle and the connection, but it's easy to do it directly.

Comment: Than you Ted for your time and efforts answering my questions. I think from a pedagogical perspective: why is there not a more elementary way to rigorously show what I was stuck with is true? Sometimes, one, like me, is stuck with something that sounds the most natural and easiest to someone else. It would be great if you or someone can provide an elementary and explicit proof. Thanks.

Comment: I found an elementary and rigorous proof of the part I was stuck with in M. Spivak’s vol 2, which uses parallel transport of orthogonal vector fields along the curve $gamma$. Thanks everyone

Comment: @Chee: See the edit (you may want to check if Spivak missed cases b and c).

Comment: @Deane: See the edit.

Comment: @Moishe, thank you a lot  for providing details in your answer, and thank everyone for helping me! The 2 identities in the question are fundamental to Riemannian geometry. It is going to leave a dent in one's intellectual understanding if they are not completely understood. Further, the technique of using parallel orthogonal vector fields along a curve is very useful (which is also used in estimations related to Jacobi fields and in proving comparison theorems). Your comments and answers will benefit many readers, in particular, those who are self-teaching.